# parse.com : send push notification from my own CMS

Tags: php, android, ios, parsing, push

I want to use the Parse.com api to send push notifications but I need to send these push notifications from my CMS in PHP ...and not from Dashboard from parse.com. **Its possible to integrate my CMS with parse`s dashboard?  I have tried search in parse's doc but haven't found**

here is the panel form

```
</div>
    <div class="section_body">
        <div id="push_errors" style="display: block;">Your message cannot be empty</div>
        <div class="ui_action_button disabled" id="send_push"><span>Send now</span><i class="icon_send"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#installations/PHP

```
$data = array("alert" => "Hi!");

ParsePush::send(array(
  "channels" => ["PHPFans"],
  "data" => $data
));
```

or:

```
$query = ParseInstallation::query();
$query->equalTo("design", "rad");
ParsePush::send(array(
  "where" => $query,
  "data" => $data
));
```

Comment: Thx, it works...I accept as the answer because you are the first

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible. Have a look at their docs here: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending/PHP

For example (copied from docs):

> "With the PHP SDK, the following code can be used to alert all
>   subscribers of the "Giants" and "Mets" channels about the results of
>   the game. This will display a notification center alert to iOS users
>   and a system tray notification to Android users."

```
$data = array("alert" => "Hi!");

ParsePush::send(array(
  "channels" => ["PHPFans"],
  "data" => $data
))
```